# Re-installing OS X with apartment Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, wifi, install

I need to re-install OS X Lion and I'm at a stage where when I turn my laptop on, it needs an internet connection to proceed.

I have a good strong Wi-Fi signal, but I need to sign in. I usually do this by opening Safari, which prompts me with the sign-in page. I can't open Safari though because I'm in the re-install screen.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Also, what's the proper terminology used here?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd try to just connect to the Wi-Fi network and then run the recovery. But this will not work if you have a new and empty hard drive (i.e. no OS X  recovery partition on the hard drive) and need a full Internet Recovery from Apple's server.

If it doesn't work, I'd try and connect the Mac to another Mac or a Windows PC using a common Ethernet cable (network cable) and enable "Internet Sharing" on that system. On a Mac, Internet Sharing is simply enabled via System Preferences > Sharing. I don't know how this is done in Windows.

If that doesn't work either, I'd simply see that I connect the Mac to a different Wifi or ethernet-based network that doesn't require you to go through such a captive portal. Just remember not to enter any account credentials over public Wi-Fi (such as your Apple ID).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, you can connect via another Mac or PC using internet sharing.

Before you proceed, you need to answer this question: am I doing a full reinstall of the OS from the Internet, or do I have the ability to use a USB memory stick with Mac OS X on it to load the initial files?  USB sticks with Mac OS X on them can usually be obtained from the Apple store if you need one and that is sometimes the fastest way to get set up again.

- For install with USB stick with OS X on it.

After using the USB stick to load the initial multi gigabyte install of Mac OS X, one of the easiest options, if you have a smartphone that has a good signal in your area, is to use your phone's Wi-Fi tethering option to set up a hotspot using your phone's cell network connection. Just use it for a very short period of time, just long enough to finish the initial set up with iCloud, etc.  Then once you can log in, turn off the hotspot and use the standard Wi-Fi to proceed.

- for install without the USB stick with OS X on it
  This takes more time, and is trickier.
  You can either:
- use another computer to do this as mentioned before, with an Ethernet cable and internet sharing
- use a smartphone with a very high data limit, or unlimited data, like T-Mobile, to perform the initial load
- use a third computer to load the latest version of Mac OS X on a USB stick yourself [See how to create a bootable USB installer](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/)
- Take the computer to the Apple Store to have them perform the initial load.

My personal preference is to create a USB stick with Mac OS X on it and have that handy for when I need to do a reinstall. It's usually faster and saves needing to download things again.